# Будет ли работать такая форма опроса?

Tags: html, form

Проводится один "опрос", и там код опроса такой:

>

```html
<input type="hidden" name="interviews_id" value="26" />
<span class="title">Как вы относитесь к строительству Томинского ГОК?</span>
<div class="answers">
  <label data-answer_id="112">
    <input type="radio" name="answer[26]" value="112" /><span>Положительно. Новое производство дает рабочие места и развивает экономику Южного Урала, а экологические пикеты проплачивают наши западные враги.</span>
  </label>
  <label data-answer_id="113">
    <input type="radio" name="answer[26]" value="113" /><span>Отрицательно. ГОК слишком близко будет располагаться к городу и близлежащим населенным пунктам, тем самым окончательно уничтожит нашу и без того плохую экологию.</span>
  </label>
  <label data-answer_id="114">
    <input type="radio" name="answer[26]" value="114" /><span>Мне все равно, меня это никак не затрагивает. </span>
  </label>
  <label data-answer_id="115">
    <input type="radio" name="answer[26]" value="115" /><span>Покину регион сразу, как запустится ГОК.</span>
  </label>
  <label data-answer_id="116">
    <input type="radio" name="answer[26]" value="116" /><span>Не знаю, буду смотреть по ситуации. Не исключено, что найду себе там применение.</span>
  </label>
</div>
<a href="#answer" class="big-but">Ответить</a>
<div class="info">
  <p>Проголосовало человек: <span class="answers-count">7170</span>
  </p>
  <p><a href="#result">Посмотреть результаты</a>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Я считаю, что это фальшивая форма, 
а мне пишут, что на самом деле: "код формы обрабатывается через jquery и отправляется на сервер".

Посмотреть можно тут www.cheltv.ru (3 экран)

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: непраильно код вставил, можно смотреть

Comment: @pontekorvo, это Ajax, а вопрос нужно закрывать.

Comment: Все равно ничего не понял. Если вопрос в том, может ли теоретически такая структура использоваться для записи ответов, то да, может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно Вам сказали.

Выбирете вариант ответа и жмете "Ответить".
Далее идет AJAX call в `/ajax/interviews` и вместе с ним передается Ваш ответ.
Обратно получается JSON объект с процентными данными по каждому варианту ответа.

Так что все правильно Вам сказали - форма рабочая.

Ну а если Вам все-таки нужна интрига, то ........ вот что происходит внутри `/ajax/interviews`, действительно ли там все учитывается и выдается реальный ответ или там подделка - этого узнать мы не можем...